# Spark submit REST cluster/standalone mode - launching an s3a jar with STS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

```
/var/lib/spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master spark://myhost:6066 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key='redact1' --conf spark.executorEnv.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='redact1' --conf spark.driverEnv.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='redact1' --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key='redact2' --conf spark.executorEnv.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='redact2' --conf spark.driverEnv.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='redact2' --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token='redact3' --conf spark.executorEnv.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN='redact3' --conf spark.driverEnv.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN='redact3' --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-DAWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=redact1 -DAWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=redact2 -DAWS_SESSION_TOKEN=redact3' --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-DAWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=redact1 -DAWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=redact2 -DAWS_SESSION_TOKEN=redact3' --total-executor-cores 4 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 2g --driver-memory 1g --name lin1 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false --class com.yotpo.metorikku.Metorikku s3a://mybuc/metorikku_2.11.jar -c s3a://mybuc/spark_ingestion_job.yaml
```

running the above command give below stack trace:

```
    Exception from the cluster:\njava.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://mybuc/metorikku_2.11.jar: getFileStatus on s3a://mybuc/metorikku_2.11.jar: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: xx; S3 Extended Request ID: /1qj/yy=), S3 Extended Request ID: /1qj/yy=\n\
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:158)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:101)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1542)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:117)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isFile(FileSystem.java:1463)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.isFile(S3AFileSystem.java:2030)
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchHcfsFile(Utils.scala:747)
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:723)
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:509)
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:155)
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:173)
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:92)
```

all the ec2s in the spark cluster only have access to s3 via STS tokens. The jar itself reads csvs from s3 using the tokens, and everything works if either 1. i change the commandline to point to local jars on the ec2 OR 2. use port 7077/client mode instead of cluster mode. But it seems the jar itself can't be launched off s3, as if the tokens are not being picked up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be applying every single option that you can and that is probably adding even more confusion.

1. Make sure hadoop-aws JAR's S3A connector has its TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider, which means hadoop 2.8+. IF you are still using a spark release with the 2.7 binaries: stop it.
2. Unset the env vars locally. Spark launch will pick them up and cause confusion.
3. set the s3a access key info in spark-default file. Spark will pick them up from job launch and pass them on.

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key ASIXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key H9rJS...vNX 
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token Fw0gz...ZQL 
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider
```

I generate session keys enough I've a tool to do it:
https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/releases/tag/tag_2021_07_02-release
This will request tokens locally and print out the bash, fish, CLI, spark and hadoop XML options.

(note: completely unsupported & needs a local hadoop-3.3.x installation to work. The issued tokens can be used anywhere)

If it's just during download of the actual JAR containing your code, this may be some spark bootstrap issue.

- Easiest solution: make that bucket/path readable by the IAM role the EC2 VMs are launched as.
- Fanciest solution: hadoop-3.3.x cluster with Kerberos enabled and [S3A delegation tokens](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/delegation_tokens.html)

The delegation tokens will collect session/role secrets on your machine (i.e. get them from STS), attach them to the YARN job launch info, where they get picked up and used everywhere spark wants to talk to the given bucket.

Comment: "during download of the actual JAR containing your code, this may be some spark bootstrap issue." - this is my hunch. I tried points 1-3 but doesn't work (also 3 is a no go since each spark call should use diff token). not using yarn and IAM role off limits due to security